# C# MVC Dynamic selection of resource (resx) files

Tags: c#, .net, resources

I need to be able to extract a value from one of several different resx files in a controller.

My current approach is to use resource files in App_GlobalResources and

```
string myValue = Resources.MyResourceFile1.MyKey;
```

Thing is, in some circumstances I need to extract value from MyResourceFile2.

All the examples I can find on SO veer down the 'you're doing localization so use culture'.

That's not going to work for me.

Is there away of coding something of the effect of

```
int x = 1;
string myValue = Resources.(MyResourcefile + x).MyKey;
```

Comment: If you refuse to use culture for localization, then you maybe use reflection?

Comment: That's what I was thinking, just not too sure how to go about it.